# Add time management for each project in Trello

Tags: trello

Is it possible to add time management in Trello?

For example, if we work on a project I want to be able to do monthly reports to see how much time was used/spent on a certain project. How can I set this up in Trello?

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this card](https://trello.com/c/9tX8CRNm) on our Trello Devello board.

Answer (score 0):

See also [Plus for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plus-for-trello/gjjpophepkbhejnglcmkdnncmaanojkf) Chrome Extension to track Spent and Estimate with a lot of reporting features.